# Is language translation algorithm non-deterministic in nature?

Tags: algorithm, google-translate, language-translation, google-translation-api

A few days ago, I got a Thai translation of the string "Reward points issues" as "คะแนนสะสม".

But when I checked it today, the Google translator gave a different Thai translation - "ประเด็นคะแนนรางวัล"

So, I am guessing the algorithm might be non-deterministic.

But, there is a thing that I am not able to understand. In any language, new words are added everyday and not new characters and not new ways to form a pre-defined word. Then why did Google Translate gave a different output?

Also, is my assumption of non-deterministic nature correct?

NOTE: I could observe same behaviour with other languages like russian, dutch, chinese, and polish.

Comment: Hi @DeepakTatyajiAhire, How are you trying to translate the text into different languages? I tried using [rest api](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text#translate_translate_text-drest) to translate text into different languages that you have mentioned, it gave me the same results every time. Can you try using client libraries or rest api to translate text? Let me know if you're still facing the issue.

Comment: Hello @PrajnaRaiT. I am using the Google Translate API

Comment: Hi @DeepakTatyajiAhire, Could you provide more information on which API method you used to send translation request to the Cloud Translation? Could you provide a sample API call?

Comment: This issue has been raised in this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/243127921). However, we cannot provide an ETA at the moment but you can “STAR” the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) .

Answer (score 1):

> A few days ago, I got a Thai translation of the string "Reward points issues" as "คะแนนสะสม".
>
> But when I checked it today, the Google translator gave a different Thai translation - "ประเด็นคะแนนรางวัล"

The translation by Google Translate sometimes depends on previous translations done on the same Google Translate tab, for some language pairs. This may explain your observation.

> Is language translation algorithm non-deterministic in nature?

No, but the model designer may choose to add some diversity/randomness by allowing the model to give different outputs for the same input, e.g. via higher [temperature](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/613011/12359) or via intentionally not always choosing the top-1 candidate with the highest log-probability among the n candidates of a beam search. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.00201.pdf:

> Beam search is the most widely used decoding method for neural machine translation (NMT). In practice, the top-1 candidate with the highest log-probability among the n candidates is selected as the preferred one. However, this top-1 candidate may not be the best overall translation among the n-best list.

But in practice, the deployed language translation algorithms are typically deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the algorithms used by Google are non-deterministic, there is no reason for them to be.

Anyway Google translates by reference to a huge corpus of known translations. This corpus is constantly updated and this influences day-by-day translations. It is made of complete sentences rather than isolated words.

In fact Google translation... learns.